# Very low bounce rate in google analytic

Tags: google-analytics

I know a low bounce rate is due to double tracking but I don't find the problem on [that website](http://www.mon-animal-epileptique.fr)

The tracking code is this one:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-12345678-9"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-12345678-9', {  
                                        'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'Appli'}
                                    } );

    gtag('set', {'user_id': '1'});
    gtag('event', 'page_web', {'Appli': 'non'});
</script>
```

I don't see how to remove something...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that you are setting an `event` on page load. By default the `gtag` tag will first create a `pageview` hit that is sent to Google Analytics.

Then your `gtag('event', 'page_web', {'Appli': 'non'});` call is fired. Because this is an interaction event, it will count as a user interaction, and thus the bounce rate for the page will be zero (a bounce is recorded if there are no interaction hits after a pageview hit on a single page).

I'm not sure what you are using the event for, but if it is something that is recording automatically, then I would suggest configuring it as a non-interaction event hit:

`gtag('event', 'page_web', {'Appli': 'non', 'non_interaction': true});`

Comment: I use that code to record if the website is called from an mobile app or not. I will try and validate your answer if it works, thank you !